# Function "WSAStringToAddress" does not work with shorthand ipv6 notation ::1, works fine when using complete notation 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am trying to compile socket programming example on windows 8 using mingw (gcc 4.9.3). When using full expression of ipv6 address 
WCHAR IPAddr[256] = L"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"; it works fine, but using WCHAR IPAddr[256] = L"::1"; returns error code 10022.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>


WCHAR IPAddr[256] = L"::1";

SOCKADDR_IN6  MyAddrValue;
MyAddrValue.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
int MyAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);

RetVal = WSAStringToAddress(
(LPTSTR)IPAddr,   // Pointer to address string to be converted
AF_INET /* AF_INET*/,                  // address family
NULL,  // Protocol info structure, not useable here
(LPSOCKADDR)&MyAddrValue,  // Socket address string buffer [out]
&MyAddrSize   // Length of socket structure
);
```

Comment: `(LPTSTR)IPAddr` -- Why are you casting to `LPTSTR`?  You should never cast string types, since it indicates you're trying to suppress a legitimate compiler error concerning differing string types / pointers.  If you can't simply specify `IPAddr` without casting, then there is a problem that you're hiding, and the compiler is conveying this information to you.

Comment: I am trying to use this windows API function (WSAStringToAddress) for string to address conversion of IP(s). The source where input "IPAddr" is generated is using different types due to which type casting has to be done somewhere if not while passing as function argument as (LPTSTR)IPAddr. I will try without casting , but my problem is it works with full ipv6 expression and for some reasons it doesn't seem to recognize the compressed ipv6 notation ::1

Comment: You were right about type casting, I got it working by calling unicode version of the function explicitly WSAStringToAddressW and passing the argument simply as IPAddr, without any type casting. Also had to change the second argument address family to AF_INET6. Now it works for shortened ipv6 address (::1) also.

Comment: If you needed to explicitly call the unicode version, be aware that you are building an application using MBCS as the default character set type.  In this day and age, MBCS applications are rare, if ever produced.   Also, the reason why it didn't work is that casting does not convert the wide string to a narrow string.  Instead, the function saw the `\0` character in the string right after the first non-null byte, and assumed that was the end of the string.